# jquery .animate doesn't work on my website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make jQuery detect my swipe and then keep scrolling for me.
jQuery detects my swipe with touchswipe but the animation doesn't work.
The innerHTML part works.

I tried other animations like changing height and width but it still wont work.

I am using IOS Safari so I do not know if its testable on Chrome.

```html
<ul id="sportCourtsRow">
  <div style="margin-left: 32vw;">
    {% for c in courtsB %}
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="sportCourts" class="sportCourts"><span class="sportsCourtsTxt">{{c}}</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</ul>
```

```js
var swipebar = document.getElementById("sportCourtsRow");
$(swipebar).swipe({
  swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
    if (distance > 80) {
      document.getElementById("monthTxt").innerHTML = "worked"; //test if swipe worked.
      $("#sportCourtsRow").animate({
        "marginLeft": "500px"
      }, "slow")
    }
  },
  threshold: 0
});
```

```css
#sportCourtsRow {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 28vh;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #dfdddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.sportsCourtsTxt {
  font-family: 'alef';
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  margin-right: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the JQuery script I used was not working properly.
Heres the working one:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```